# insert elements into an array, with conditions, the fastest way

Tags: python, numpy

```
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import product


    N = 3
    P = 13
    A = np.random.random_sample((P, N))
    heh = product(range(1,4), repeat=13)
    mymat =  np.array([letters for letters in heh], dtype=np.float)


    for i in range(0,len(mymat)):
     for j in range(0,(mymat.shape[1])):
        if(mymat[i,j] == 1):
           mymat[i,j] = A[j, 0]
        if(mymat[i,j] == 2):
           mymat[i,j] = A[j, 1]
        if(mymat[i,j] == 3):
           mymat[i, j] = A[j, 2]
```

I realize a nested for loop isn't optimal and the if statements are probably almost as bad.
I've been trying with using ':' instead of 'i' for the row index. Also tried:

```
   mymat[mymat[:,i]==1] = A[i,0]
```

It didn't work though, in R I just used:

```
       a <- letters[1:3]
       eg <- expand.grid(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a)

       for (i in 1:ncol(eg)) {
       eg[,i] <- as.character(eg[,i])
       eg[,i][eg[,i] == "a"] = mat[i,1]
       eg[,i][eg[,i] == "b"] = mat[i,2]
       eg[,i][eg[,i] == "c"] = mat[i,3]
       eg[,i] <- as.numeric(eg[,i])
       }
```

Been trying to translate it into python, but just can't get it to work fast enough.

Comment: Can you clarify with example input and output what you would like (use a simplified version of the problem!). This definitely seems like something very manageable in `numpy`, but I don't quite understand the question...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with broadcasting using the `where` statement; for example:

```
for col, val in enumerate([1, 2, 3]):
    i, j = np.where(mymat == val)
    mymat[i, j] = A[j, col]
```

Edit: there's an even faster way to do this by exploiting the fact that within the example you gave, the values are everywhere 1 larger than the indices:

```
mymat = A[np.arange(mymat.shape[1]), mymat.astype(int) - 1]
```

This makes use of the fact that indexing with an array returns a result that is the shape of the index array.